# Error: Template parse errors: 'selector' is not a known element. How to Import Component form another module

Tags: angular, components, ng-modules

How to import component from another module?

Project Structure:

```
|
|-users.module.ts // (i.e. exports: [AddressComponent])
|--profile.component.ts
|--address.component.ts
|
|-customer.module.ts
|--basket.component.ts
|
|-app.component.ts
```

Address component is exported list inside **users.module.ts**, its selector works in **app.component.ts**'s template but not in **basket.component.ts**

Comment: Did you import the UserModule in CustomerModule?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the `AddressComponent` as a `declaration`.

Answer (score -2):

You have to import address.component in basket.component using import statement.